# Liquibase transaction demarcation

Tags: java, mysql, innodb, liquibase

I have 2 examples of Liquibase changesets where the second statements are failing(trying to insert a record with existing primary key), but the first ones are successful:

Failing/no record in databasechangelog:

```
--changeset yura:2
insert into test2 values (4, 'test4');
insert into test2 values (2, 'test2');
```

Partially written, no record in databasechangelogg:

```
--changeset yura:2
insert into test2 values (4, 'test4');
ALTER TABLE test2 ADD name varchar(50);
```

When I try to run those statements on MySql directly, the behaviour is consistent for both because MySql(InnoDB) will wrap every statement in a separate transaction.
Why is Liquibase not consistent?

Comment: Check on `autocommit`.  Also, `ALTER` will terminate any transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think I will be able to answer it myself after some further investigation.
Some statements, due to multiple reasons one of which is that they are very hard to rollback, will perform and implicit commit *before* they execute.
You can check it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).
At the same time, Liquibase has an interesting [configuration](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) by default:

> **runInTransaction**  Should the changeSet be ran as a single transaction (if possible)? **Defaults to true.**

If you put those two facts together, the answer becomes obvious:
When there is an ALTER inside a cahngeset, it will be implicitly demarcated from the previous statements. Courtesy of DB itself. Liquibase can not influence this low-level DB feature. However, Liquibase will be able to group statements into 1 transaction, when those statements do not require implicit commit.